# Downgrade Visual Studio 2015 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2008 *.sln file. However, I can't open it using Visual Studio 2008 Express. It is unable to load the projects. I suspect it might be limited functionalities in the Express edition.

I also have an existing copy of Visual Studio 2015. Do I need to "downgrade" my Visual Studio 2015 to 2008 in order to open the *.sln file?

Edit 1:
[image]

Edit 2:
[image]

Comment: *Downgrading* would mean uninstalling 2015 and installing 2008. You've already said that 2008 won't open the file, so what benefit would you get? What does *unable to load the projects* mean *specifically*? What is the actual problem you're having opening the projects?

Comment: No you don't but once you bring the sln up to 2015 it can't go back so back it up.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your reply. Please see the edits. I opened the file in 2008 Express edition. But there's some errors. I presume it might be due to the limitations of an Express edition.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thank you for your reply. I don't have an option to bring it up to any version. It is still in 2008 version. But I am facing a problem because I couldn't open it in 2008 Express version.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to downgrade as all version of Visual Studio can exist side by side.

You can easily install the full Visual Studio 2008 on the same machine as Visual Studio 2015. If you have an MSDN licence then you can just download 2008 and install..